# Saved data not ready after redirection - PlayFramework 1.2.4

Tags: playframework

Using Play Framework 1.2.4, if I post some data to an action and then redirect to another action, like this for example:

```
public static void post(Entity entity)
{
    entity.save();
    index();
}
```

The data that I just saved (entity.save()) has not become ready at this point. So if index() is supposed to list all the entities including the one I just created, it will not. I have to reload the page to see that entity in the list.

Anyone experienced this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This should not be the case. When you call `index()`, Play performs a browser redirect, so the server has entirely completed the request, and a brand new request is made to execute the index action.

I think your error must be somewhere else because what you are describing is very common practice in Play applications, and I have never seen the behaviour your are describing before.

Comment: I dunno. It used to work, probably using 1.2.2. I put the save() part into a job and waited for it to be finished. That seemed to solve the problem. I just wish I didn't have to do that every time I want to save something. I also tried to commit the transaction inside the controller, but that didn't work - maybe I didn't do it right. Btw, this happens locally only, I think (I guess on the prod server it doesn't go as fast)

Comment: Actually, after trying a bit more, the Job-thing doesn't work. It works sometimes and sometimes not.

Comment: Thread.sleep(1000) seems to solve the problem, but then I again, I shouldn't block.

Comment: it may be a hibernate thing, between saving the entity and actually committing it to the database, but I have never seen this ever...

Comment: Check `play.pool` in `application.conf`, you are likely running single threaded in `dev` mode and could explain different behavior in `prod` depending on how you are deploying your app

Comment: Thanks Michael. That didn't occur to me, that it could be a dev/single-thread issue. I will look into this.